# JSONArray parsing laravel 4

Tags: json, laravel-4

I want to parse json and save all data to database.
Here is my json:

```
[{
"date": "2016/04/01",
"mac": "C9:3F:C1:B1:6F:1F",
"id": 16,
"dest": 0,
"melvalue": 22
}, {
"date": "2016/03/31",
"mac": "C9:3F:C1:B1:6F:1F",
"id": 1,
"dest": 0,
"melvalue": 0
}, {
"date": "2016/03/30",
"mac": "C9:3F:C1:B1:6F:1F",
"id": 2,
"dest": 0,
"melvalue": 0
}]
```

How can I do this? please help.

```
{
"date": "2016/03/17",
"mac": "C9:3F:C1:B1:6F:1F",
"id": 15,
"dest": 12,
"melvalue": 0
}
```

will be my one row of table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-Steps will be something like as 
    -- Read all data from source in controller function

```
$arraytoIterate =  json_decode('Yor json string here to go');

-- Create a model for that table

-- create dataArray and save the data in your controllers function as below
```

---

```
    $arraytoIterate =  json_decode('Yor json string here to go');

    foreach($arraytoIterate as $newArr){
         // hope table columns name will be same as of json object column name
         ModelName::create($newArr) // for adding records
     }
```

---